# Google Search Console reports empty brand and model of product

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, structured-data, json-ld, products

Google Search Console: Structured Data > Product (markup: schema.org)
[image]

Parsed in Google:

[image]

Brand and model JSON:

> ```
>   "brand":{  
>      "@type":"Thing",
>      "name":"Volkswagen"
>   },
>   "model":{  
>      "@type":"ProductModel",
>      "name":"Passat CC"
>   },
> ```

Our JSON-LD full:

```
[  
   {  
      "@context":"http://schema.org",
      "@type":"BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement":[  
         {  
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position":1,
            "item":{  
               "@id":"https://example.com/#!төмөр-хүлэг/",
               "name":"Төмөр хүлэг"
            }
         },
         {  
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position":2,
            "item":{  
               "@id":"https://example.com/#!төмөр-хүлэг/зарах/",
               "name":"Зарах"
            }
         },
         {  
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position":3,
            "item":{  
               "@id":"https://example.com/#!төмөр-хүлэг/зарах/авто-мото/",
               "name":"Авто & Мото"
            }
         },
         {  
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position":4,
            "item":{  
               "@id":"https://example.com/#!төмөр-хүлэг/зарах/авто-мото/суудлын/",
               "name":"Суудлын"
            }
         },
         {  
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position":5,
            "item":{  
               "@id":"https://example.com/#!төмөр-хүлэг/зарах/авто-мото/суудлын/нийтлэг/",
               "name":"Нийтлэг"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "@context":"http://schema.org",
      "@type":"Product",
      "name":" Volkswagen Passat CC, 2010/2011 Бензин 2.0л",
      "image":[  
         "https://example.com/images/items/2018/06/07/234331/volkswagen-passat-cc-зарна_00_medium.jpeg",
         "https://example.com/images/items/2018/06/07/234331/volkswagen-passat-cc-зарна_01_medium.jpeg",
         "https://example.com/images/items/2018/06/07/234331/volkswagen-passat-cc-зарна_02_medium.jpeg",
         "https://example.com/images/items/2018/06/07/234331/volkswagen-passat-cc-зарна_03_medium.jpeg",
         "https://example.com/images/items/2018/06/07/234331/volkswagen-passat-cc-зарна_04_medium.jpeg",
         "https://example.com/images/items/2018/06/07/234331/volkswagen-passat-cc-зарна_05_medium.jpeg",
         "https://example.com/images/items/2018/06/07/234331/volkswagen-passat-cc-зарна_06_medium.jpeg",
         "https://example.com/images/items/2018/06/07/234331/volkswagen-passat-cc-зарна_07_medium.jpeg"
      ],
      "description":"Хийх юмгүй сайхан зарна. машин оролцуулж болно",
      "mpn":"234331",
      "brand":{  
         "@type":"Thing",
         "name":"Volkswagen"
      },
      "model":{  
         "@type":"ProductModel",
         "name":"Passat CC"
      },
      "additionalProperty":[  
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Үйлдвэрлэгч улс",
            "value":"Герман"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Үйлдвэрлэгч",
            "value":"Volkswagen"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Загвар",
            "value":"Passat"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Цуврал",
            "value":"CC"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Төлөв",
            "value":"Монголд ашигласан"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Шатахуун зарцуулалт",
            "value":"9 л/100км"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Үйлдвэрлэсэн он",
            "value":"2010-01"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Импортлогдсон он",
            "value":"2011-01"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Хурдны хайрцаг",
            "value":"Механик"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Хөдөлгүүрийн төрөл",
            "value":"Дан"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Хөдөлгүүрийн тэжээл",
            "value":"Бензин"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Цилиндрийн багтаамж",
            "value":"2000 см3"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Туулсан зам",
            "value":"76000 км"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Хөтлөгч",
            "value":"Урд"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Жолооны хүрд",
            "value":"Зөв Зүүн"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Суудлын тоо",
            "value":5
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Хаалганы тоо",
            "value":4
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Будалт",
            "value":"Энгийн"
         },
         {  
            "@type":"PropertyValue",
            "name":"Өнгө",
            "value":"Саарал"
         }
      ],
      "offers":{  
         "@type":"Offer",
         "priceCurrency":"MNT",
         "price":"17000000.00",
         "priceValidUntil":"2018-07-07",
         "itemCondition":"https://schema.org/UsedCondition",
         "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
         "url":"https://example.com/#!төмөр-хүлэг/зарах/авто-мото/суудлын/нийтлэг/234331/volkswagen-passat-cc-зарна",
         "areaServed":{  
            "@type":"State",
            "name":"Улаанбаатар"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: No idea if this is the reason, but you are using `Thing` as value for `brand`, but the property expects either a `Brand` or an `Organization` value.

Comment: it's from here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product

Comment: Backing up the others. I've found those columns to be very fussy about how the items are marked up. It may only support brand as text.